# Fill base inherited class as one object rather than linking each attribute

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the following scenario

Scenario 1:

```
public class TT : t
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public TT(t name, int name2)
    {
        this.att1 = name.att1;
        this.att2 = name.att2;
        this.att3 = name.att3;
        x = name2;
    }
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
public class TT : t
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public TT(t name, int name2)
    {
        this = name;
        x = name2;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pass the base inherited class "t" as an entire object, rather than having to assign each property from the base class's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass the base inherited class "t" as an entire object, rather than having to assign each property from the base class's properties?

No. You can't reassign `this` in the constructor of a class (or any other method).  Also, remember that `name` will be a *reference* to an object, not the object itself, so even if you *could* reassign `this`, you'd be pointing to the same object, not copying its values.

You will need to copy the values from the source class field-by-field.  Whether you do that in this constructor or in a base constructor (which would be helpful if you have multiple sub-classes that you want to add this functionality to), and whether you do it explicitly or using reflection is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [copy constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116.aspx) in the base class and use it like this:

```
public class TT : t
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public TT(t name, x name2):base(name)
    {
        x = name2;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to handle the base copy constructor manually you can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) and [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) to automatize it